# Hide column if column is empty i.e. array element is empty

Tags: php, html

I have an array such:

```
  $prices = array();
```

Along with a MySQL query and fetch:

```
$query = "SELECT $columns FROM Prices WHERE `key` LIKE '$rows' LIKE '$AirportPU' AND rate LIKE '$rate'";

 if($results = $db->query($query))
 {
 if($results->num_rows)
 {
 while($row = $results->fetch_object())
 {
 $prices[] = $row;
 }
 $results->free();
 }
```

I've printed out the table using the following code: (I have removed some table columns)

```
<?php 
if(!count($prices)) {
    echo '<p>No results found for your current search. Use the inputs to the left to change the filters.</p>';
 } else {
   ?>
       <table>
           <thead>
               <tr>
                <th>Location</th>
                <th>City</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <?php
              foreach ($prices as $p) {
              ?>
              <tr>
                <td> <?php echo $p->Location; ?> </td>
                <td> £<?php echo $p->City; ?> </td>
              </tr>
              <?php
              }
              ?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        <?php } ?>
```

I can return data from the MySQL query, and print this to the table. However, sometimes not all the columns need be printed as they have no values. I would like to hide these columns.

I have tried checking the array using:

```
print (isset($prices["City"])) ? "Exists</br>" : "Doesn't Exist</br>" ;
```

But that always returns "Doesn't Exist"

```
if (array_key_exists("City",$prices))
{
echo "Element exists!";
}
else
{
echo "Element does not exist!";
}
```

That also returns false.

Comment: Try empty() check instead of isset(), see more here http://techtalk.virendrachandak.com/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/

Comment: Ah sorry, i did try empty first, forgot to mention that. same result :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check it inside the `foreach` loop which you are executing.

```
print (isset($p->City)) ? "Exists</br>" : "Doesn't Exist</br>" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with

```
if(empty($price['City'] || $price['City'] == "")){
    //Hide column
}
```

Comment: if( is_empty($price['City'])){
        echo "No data";
     } 
     else if (is_empty($price['City']) == false) {
         echo "data";
            }

Tried this: the rest of my page isnt displaying? not sure whats wrong

Comment: Sorry is_empty is not a function. It's empty();